# Change Executable Version Info

Tags: vb.net

I'm new in VB, i'm using VB 2010 Express and I want to change the Executable Version Info, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on your project in the IDE, select properties, select the application tab and click on Assembly Information. or you can edit the AssemblyInfo.vb file.

Answer (score 0):

Locate your AssemblyInfo file.  The version tag is in there.